# Obtener página web cargada a través de javascript

Tags: javascript, java, web

Estoy tratando de loguearme en una web con javascript. Ejecuto el código javascript por fuera y consigo loguearme, ahora bien, desde java, ejecuto ese código y trato de acceder a una página concreta con el id de producto y me pide loguearme otra vez. No sé que estoy haciendo mal. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
package blog.article2;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Authenticator {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String baseUrl = "https://www.miweb.com/producto/?productID=6007020" ;
    String loginUrl = "https://www.miweb.com/" ; 

    try {
        System.out.println("Starting autoLogin on " + loginUrl);
        WebClient client = autoLogin(loginUrl);
        HtmlPage page = client.getPage(baseUrl) ;

        String originalHtml = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
        writeFile(originalHtml, "original.html");
        System.out.println(originalHtml);
        if(originalHtml.contains("'price': '"))
        {
            String precio = originalHtml.split("'price': '")[1].split("'")[0];
            System.out.println(originalHtml);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static WebClient autoLogin(String loginUrl) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    HtmlPage page = client.getPage(loginUrl);

    page.executeJavaScript("javascript: {" +
            "document.getElementById(\"form_postalcode\").innerHTML = \"<select id='cl_postal_code' class='postalCodesSelect form-control form_field select2-hidden-accessible' data-validation-engine='validate[required]' title='' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placeholder='Código Postal' tabindex='-1' data-original-title='Por favor, selecciona un código postal' aria-hidden='true'><option></option><option value='15001'>15001</option><option value='15002'>15002</option><option value='15003'>15003</option><option value='15004'>15004</option><option value='15005'>15005</option><option value='15006'>15006</option><option value='15007'>15007</option><option value='15008'>15008</option><option value='15009'>15009</option><option value='24100'>24100</option><option value='24110'>24110</option><option value='24111'>24111</option><option value='24112'>24112</option><option value='24113'>24113</option><option value='24114'>24114</option><option value='47012'>47012</option><option value='47013'>47013</option><option value='47014'>47014</option><option value='47015'>47015</option><option value='47016'>47016</option><option value='47130'>47130</option><option value='47140'>47140</option><option value='47151'>47151</option><option value='47155'>47155</option><option value='47193'>47193</option><option value='47194'>47194</option><option value='47195'>47195</option><option value='47220'>47220</option><option value='47400'>47400</option><option value='47450'>47450</option><option value='47454'>47454</option><option value='47460'>47460</option><option value='47463'>47463</option><option value='47465'>47465</option><option value='47490'>47490</option><option value='47491'>47491</option><option value='47492'>47492</option><option value='47493'>47493</option><option value='47494'>47494</option><option value='47500'>47500</option><option value='47509'>47509</option><option value='47610'>47610</option></select><span class='select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--above select2-container--open' dir='ltr' style='width: 210px;'><span class='selection'><span class='select2-selection select2-selection--single' role='combobox' aria-autocomplete='list' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true' title='' tabindex='5' aria-labelledby='select2-cl_postal_code-container' data-toggle='tooltip' data-original-title='Por favor, selecciona un código postal' aria-owns='select2-cl_postal_code-results'><span class='select2-selection__rendered' id='select2-cl_postal_code-container' aria-label='NUEVO CLIENTE. Por favor, selecciona un código postal' title='15002'>15002</span><span class='select2-selection__arrow' role='presentation'><b role='presentation'></b></span></span></span><span class='dropdown-wrapper' aria-hidden='true'></span></span>\";" + 
            " };");

    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000);

    page.executeJavaScript("javascript: {" +
            "document.getElementById(\"cl_postal_code\").value = \"15002\";" +
            "$('.btn_new_client').click(); " +
            " };");
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30 * 1000);

    return client;
}

/*
 * Metodo de escritura de ficheros
 */
public static void writeFile(String contenido, String nombre) {
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        File logFile = new File(nombre);

        // This will output the full path where the file will be written to...
        System.out.println(logFile.getCanonicalPath());

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile));
        writer.write(contenido);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            // Close the writer regardless of what happens...
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Buenas! Has mirado el tema de las cookies ?

Comment: Revisa en tu navegador ejemplo Chrome con la extensión de desarrollador y analiza los request y response . Revisa si se ejecuta otro script que comprueba que no es un robot el que hace la consulta. Trata de incluir Headers en tu request.  En los Headers seguramente se debe enviar qué tipo de navegador hace la petición,  cookies, tokens, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He analizado los request al loguearme en la web y se ejecutan 33 scripts que no parece que bloqueen este acceso. Cada script tiene sus headers, aparecen las generales, las de request y las de response. Entiendo que con utilizar las de request sería suficiente pero al añadirlas me sigue mostrando la misma página inicial... alguna sugerencia o web dónde pueda comprobar que lo estoy haciendo bien? Gracias de antemano